# `source` command: .csh and .sh file not found even though `ls` clearly lists it?

Tags: linux, source

[image]

As you can see, for some reason the `source` command says the file wasn't found even though it's clearly in the directory. I show the first bit of the output of `cat` as well: it shows the first line as being `#!/bin/bash -p` which I think is correct for the `source` command?

The freesurfer installation guide (https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/DownloadAndInstall) tells you to run these two lines

`export FREESURFER_HOME=/usr/local/freesurfer`

`source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh`

I've tried this as well but I get the same not found error. I made sure the directory was correct.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm a huge beginner. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The shell is complaining about the `source` command, not about your files.

Your shell seems to be `/bin/sh`, which may be the `dash` shell.  When `dash` is running as `sh`, it's a POSIX shell and therefore does not have a `source` command. The `source` command is an extension to the standard, usually the same or similar as the standard `.` (dot) command.

Therefore, if you want to source those files in your `/bin/sh` shell, then use the `.` command:

```
. "$FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh"
```

Or, change your shell to a shell, like `bash`, that implements the `source` command.

Note also that the `#!` line is irrelevant in these kind of "dot scripts" as the script is read by the current shell and not by an external interpreter.